# Realizar búsqueda combinando campos desde Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

estoy desarrollando un sistema en donde tengo que hacer una consulta utilizando Eloquent con la particularidad de que se deben combinar varios campos pero no todos a la vez, debe ser dinámica en función de lo que especifique el usuario. A continuación, les muestro parte del código que estoy utilizando:

```
$this->lstMaterialesPublic = bibDNPC_mae_materiales::where(function($query){
    if ($this->cadBusqueda!=''){
        $query->where('abstract', 'like', '%' . $this->cadBusqueda . '%');
    }

    if ($this->fil_coleccion!=''){
        $query->where('identifColec', '=', $this->fil_coleccion);
    }

    if ($this->fil_autor!=''){

    }
    if ($this->fil_descriptor!=''){

    }
})->get();
```

A continuación, les explico un poco mas en detalle: los dos primeros filtros, el de cadBusqueda y el fil_coleccion, están funcionando bien debido a que allí hay una relación uno a uno, pero en los dos siguientes, fil_autor y fil_descriptor, están asociados a una consulta uno a muchos, es decir, un item de materialesPublic, puede tener mas de un autor y mas de un descriptor, mientras que solo estará asociado a una colección. Tanto los autores como los descriptores están en tablas diferentes. Existe una tabla que contiene la referencia a materialespublic y a los autores, de esa manera se agrupan los diversos autores que pueden estar vinculados a cada material. Este mismo esquema se aplica a los descriptores. Pensaba que podía verificar si fil_autor está contenido en una consulta secundaria realizada a la tabla que contiene las referencias entre materialesPublic y autores, pero no se como estructurar una consulta así.
Toda esta mecánica es necesaria porque el buscador que intento desarrollar tiene que poder buscar una cadena de texto sola o en combinación con una colección, un autor, o un descriptor y como ya había comentado antes, el problema está en que tanto para Autores como para descriptores, tengo una relación uno a muchos.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias y saludos.